# TestNG with Cucumber customized report - time of single steps execution

Tags: cucumber, testng, report

I'm trying to find the solution for add  to my tests report times of execution for all single steps available in scenario (separately). I found that there are some solutions where I can add time for whole scenario execution, with use of objects created with ITestContext and getting values- eg with getStartMillis getEndMillis.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have generate customized report by following steps.

1. Create TestCase POJO class with
2. Convert ITestResult to your Test Case
3. Generate html report using Apache Velocity Engine.

**TestCase POJO :**

```
package Reporter;

public class TestCase {
    String tcNum = null;
    Object[] tcDescr = null;
    String status = "Pass";
    String tcName = null;
    String startTime = null;
    String endTime = null;
    String TimeTaken = null;
    String comments = null;

    public String getTcNum() {
        return tcNum;
    }

    public void setTcNum(String tcNum) {
        this.tcNum = tcNum;
    }

    public Object[] getTcDescr() {
        return tcDescr;
    }

    public void setTcDescr(Object[] tcDescr) {
        this.tcDescr = tcDescr;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTcName() {
        return tcName;
    }

    public void setTcName(String tcName) {
        this.tcName = tcName;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public String getTimeTaken() {
        return TimeTaken;
    }

    public void setTimeTaken(String timeTaken) {
        TimeTaken = timeTaken;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

**Add convert Method in Listener class:**

```
public List<TestCase> tc_converter(Set<ITestResult> alltestTest){
    List<TestCase> allList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(ITestResult eachTest : alltestTest){
        TestCase tc = new TestCase();
        tc.setStartTime(new Date(eachTest.getStartMillis()).toString());
        String status = "Pass";
        if(eachTest.getStatus() != 1){
            status = "Fail";
        }
        tc.setTcName(eachTest.getName());
        tc.setStatus(status);
        tc.setEndTime(new Date(eachTest.getEndMillis()).toString());
        tc.setTcDescr(eachTest.getParameters());
        tc.setTimeTaken((eachTest.getEndMillis() - eachTest.getStartMillis()) +"");
        allList.add(tc);
    }
    return allList;
}
```

**Generate html Report:** in **onFInsh**

```
@Override
public void onFinish(ITestContext iTestContext) {
    String report_filename = iTestContext.getName().replace(" ", "_")+"_"+RandomHelper.Getdatename();
    
    String filename = "Results/" + report_filename+".html";
    int totalTcs = iTestContext.getPassedTests().getAllResults().size() + iTestContext.getFailedTests().getAllResults().size() + iTestContext.getSkippedTests().getAllResults().size();
   


    VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
    velocityEngine.init();
    Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("Inputs/report.vm");
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("tcs", iTestContext);
    context.put("passtcs", tc_converter(iTestContext.getPassedTests().getAllResults()));
    context.put("failtcs", tc_converter(iTestContext.getFailedTests().getAllResults()));
    context.put("skiptcs", tc_converter(iTestContext.getSkippedTests().getAllResults()));
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();



    t.merge( context, writer );
    try {
        FileWriter fw = null;
        fw = new FileWriter(filename);
        fw.write(writer.toString());
        fw.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    log.info(
            "Test completed on: " + iTestContext.getEndDate().toString());
    
}
```

**Final Report:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for that solution. I wilk check this on my side. But I have one question for it: in report there is added a time for full scenario? Or this is only one step in yours test scenario? I'm looking also if there is a possibility to report times of single steps eg: Scenario: Verifying_Vehicle_Deletion When Search for vehicle Then Vehicle not available (time for execution of first step  'When ...' and second step 'Then ...'). Where for example first step should take  3 s and second step 0 s.